# Find the height of each node of a tree traversing once

Tags: c++, tree

I want to find the height of each node of a tree but without going more than once for each node, can you think of something that can help me

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far and why do you think it needs multiple traversals?

Comment: The height of a tree is one plus the height of the highest subtree. (The subtrees being the trees starting at the children of the original trees root). That's a simple algorithm which is easily coded, and doesn't traverse any node more than once. Why not have a go and if you get stuck post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- What is the height of a *leaf* node? Would you need multiple traversals over that node to determine it?

  > A leaf node has a height of 1.
- If you know the height of a node's children, can you derive from that information what is the height of the node itself?

  > The height of a node that is not a leaf, is one more than the greatest height among the heights of its children.
- Which kind of traversal would you need to first determine the heights of a node's children, so that you can use that information for the node itself?

  > a post-order traversal visits a node's children before visiting the node itself.